# How to convert INR number format into European number format in Excel with Formulas?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Following is the which I am  trying :

1. Let this number 6,123,456.33 in Cell A1,
2. Then in Cell B1 use this formula =TEXT(A1,"#,###,###.##"), will give you 6,123,456.33.
3. Then in Cell C1 use this formula = SUBSTITUTE(B1,",",".") ,will give you 6.123.456.33
4. Then in Cell D1 use this formula =","&RIGHT(H12,2), will give you ,33.
5. Then again come to Cell C1 Do text to columns or other options to remove the last digits with decimals and then concatenate result with Cell D1 shows the last three digits.
6. This tip will ends up in 6.123.456,33

But Problem is in point no. 5. 
How should I remove .33 from cell C1?

TRUNC is not working on C1.

Any Suggestions ?

Comment: @Jerry : With this Custom formatting all setting will change I think so. I saw some posts in that they told like change setting Region and language. Is their other method? Because I want only number in European format.

Comment: Okay, do you want to have the result as text though?

Comment: @Jerry : I was trying to put A1 's value from object .. eg : worksheet.write(0,0, '=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(' + str(objEct['price_1']) + ',"#,###.00"),",","@"),".",","),"@",".")') But it is giving error.

Comment: worksheet.merge_range(17, 6, 17, 8, '=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXT("' + str(objEct["price_1"]) + '","#,###.00"),",","@"),".",","),"@",".")', format10) # in European format This is working for dynamic vales

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you don't mind having the result as text (and I can't seem to find a way to custom format it...) and as such, you can use the formula:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(A1,"#,###.00"),",","@"),".",","),"@",".")
```

There's a triple substitution, one to remove `,` for `@` (a dummy character), second to change `.` to `,`, then last from the dummy `@` to `.`.

Answer (score 1):

If A1 is always a 7 digit number with 2 decimals then you could use TEXT function like this:

`=TEXT(A1*100,"0\.000\.000\,00")`